# Hacking 'posts_per_page' in WP_Query

Tags: wp-query

I have a search form, a map and results section.

- Search form is submitted with different parameters
- Map shows *ALL the results that match the parameters*
- Results section shows *first 15 results that match the parameters (ordered by something)*

I currently have 2 different queries with only one difference:

- `posts_per_page` for map is `-1`
- `posts_per_page` for results is `15`

---

1. Is there a way / hack to get all the posts but show only 15 in results section?
2. Can I somehow show all the posts *(or X amount less)* without using `posts_per_page -1` and without knowing the count? This if for `WP_Query` `offset` argument that can't be used if `posts_per_page` is `-1`.

---

I know that this might seem like overcomlicating things but 2 *basically same* queries at same time with *huge amount of posts (not now but it will be)* and with *a lot of arguments*? Seems like a huge waste.

Comment: Why does the map show all results when the user has already searched for their desired results? Why wouldn't you just have the map show the results that *they* want? It's difficult to tell what you're trying to achieve but maybe `overflow: hidden` will help if you're referring to presentation?

Comment: I think you misunderstood my situation. Map shows _all_ the results that _match_ while results section shows _only first 15_ of these results that _match_ because it wouldn't be wise to load 500 different post-items with thumbnails, excerpts and few terms.

Comment: You could easily bust the query into two queries. While getting the same result pretty much the most taxing is always going to be the `posts_per_page => -1` and the `15` would be light in comparison. Another option would be use a counter and only show the first 15 results then run ajax to pull more results with an offset of 15. You would still need to rerun the query in ajax but it would be just the same at a ppp of 15. Finally, a 3rd option is to use CSS to *hide / show* your results which is faking pagination but still works. I'm not sure this is a question that can have a concrete answer.

Comment: Im currently using option 2 - I have two different queries, map query has `posts_per_page -1`, results query has `posts_per_page 15` and I use ajax with offset to load 15 more queries with every `Show more` button click. I was just thinking that while queries are exactly the same with only difference being `posts_per_page`, I could get away with only 1 query (except ajax still runs its own when `Show more` is clicked) because my query could easily have 6 `tax_query` and like 14 `meta_query` arguments if users use all the inputs and it's pretty _nasty_ to run it two times.

Comment: You can just show the first 15 results of a query- count to 15 and break out of the loop. Loops can be run multiple times on the same query object. You'll need to think this through though- if that *huge amount of posts* keeps growing, you'll eventually run out of memory and your query will produce a fatal error. You should figure out where you need to cap that now rather than when it stops working.

Comment: @Milo Thanks for that recommendation, I'll look into it. Just few small questions.. While Im currently using same query 2 times with the only difference being `posts_per_page` (_-1_ and _15_), it should be better one way or another if I use only one with `posts_per_page -1`, right?  What is _huge amount of posts_ in your opinion? I have solid automatic deletion system and expiration times set up for each post which means that I will not have a huge archive of posts that could drag my query performance down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's some options:

## Keep The AJAX

You drop out your `posts_per_page => 15` query and keep the `-1` query. Then after your map loop ( or before ) you can limit the amount of items showing using a counter:

```
if( $map->have_posts() ) : $counter = 1;
    while( $map->have_posts() && $counter <= 15 ) :
  ?>
    ...
  <?php
    $counter++;
    endwhile;
endif;
```

You could then use [`$map->rewind_posts()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/rewind_posts) respectively. Now the AJAX portion you would requery the results but since it's not happening during page-load you'll see a speed increase. You then just `offset => 15` and `posts_per_page => 15` so it's a faster query, return results and append or replace what you currently have in the results section.

---

## Simple Hide / Show

In this scenario you would want to use the [`rewind_posts()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/rewind_posts) mentioned earlier. Pretty much you would loop through *all* the results putting them in `<div>`'s of 15 ( I suggest using [modulus](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.arithmetic.php) to test this. You can then use jQuery to process when the user clicks "next" to show the next div which has a set of 15. Since you're only using 1 query the page speed will be based on the looping which will turn out to be fairly quick.

Comment: If that changes anything, form submission and getting search results is _also_ via ajax. Only the first query is run in _normal_ way if page is initially loaded (without form inputs which basically means _all results_). Your first suggestion seems like a way to go because I don't even want to think about loading times when it would have to load few hundred or more post-items each with 20-25 dom elements. But thank you, this might be what I was looking for.